# Regular expression: removing galleries

Tags: regex, string, wordpress

I do have a string like this and i don't want `[gallery columns="7"]` to be included. How can i do that using regular expression. New line there is ok.

```
[gallery columns="7"]

For sale house and lot in Cabancalan Mandaue

lot area 300 sqm
floor area 220 sqm
4 bedrooms 4 toilet and bath

with big lawn and open space

inside subdivision


for more info please contact 0932-219-4469
```

Comment: Only delete the first line in the string?

Comment: I mean in regular expression. I dont know whats the beast php function for that. You're in ruby right.

Comment: By the way [gallery columns="7"] is a dynamic it could change to 1 or 2 or 3 an so on.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
$newContent = preg_replace('/\[gallery [a-z0-9\_\-\s=\’"]+\]\s*/i', '', $oldContent);
```

It removes any occurrences of snippets like this (including any following white spaces):

```
[gallery columns="7"]
[gallery height="250" width='auto' ]
[gallery rows="2" columns="4" auto-adjust="false" ]
```

`preg_replace` documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Hope, this solves your issue.

Edit: This one also removes links and any other stuff within the square brackets:

```
$newContent = preg_replace('/\[gallery [^\]]+\]\s*/i', '', $oldContent);
```

Comment: How about the [gallery columns="7"] is in the last part of whole string. Like this: for more info [gallery columns="

Comment: should work as well. It even works with multiple galleries spread across the `$oldContent`.

Comment: our did you only want to remove galleries from the first line while leaving the rest as is? In that case, try this:
`$newContent = preg_replace('/^\s*\[gallery [a-z0-9\-\s=\’"]+\]\s*/i', '', $oldContent);`

Comment: have a look at this http://diamondpremiere.net/listings/292-sqm-lot-in-mandaue-3-million-pesos/ then click the print button.

Comment: No. All the galleries that are within the content. I need to clear theme all.

Comment: I still see gallery in this output. LOT FOR SALE IN LABOGON MANDAUE Lot areaL292 sqm Price : 3 million pesos ALONG BRGY. RD 50 METERS FROM NATIONAL HIGH WAY For more info please contact: 09322194469 /0905-228-3667 [gallery link=

Comment: can you tell me, what was following that `link=`

Comment: the regex I posted above looks for the string "[gallery " followed by any combination of these characters:
alphanum(`a-zA-Z0-9`), white spaces(`\s`) and `_-='"` if you used a variable for the link like `[gallery link=$url]` you might need to add the `$` character to the list.

Comment: Supposedly all gallery attributes must be removed. Wordpress generate link automatically that is within gallery.

Comment: I updated my original answer and added another variation. this one should remove any attributes, as long as they don't use square brackects themselves.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If so, could you accept my answer please? If it didn't help yet, I might give it another try.

Comment: BOOOMMM! You hit the hole. Amazing, thanks dude. Solve. Sory for late answer i already sleep at that time.

Comment: Happy to hear, it helped! Could you accept my answer please? It would help others, who run into the same issue. Thank you

Comment: Ohhh... That's the thing i couldn't do. It requires 15 reputation. However if i reach that requirements, I will.

Comment: I have another one problem, heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795034/wordpress-sort-post-via-terms